# Where did Black Panther go to school?

Tags: marvel, black-panther

[This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(comics)) says that the Black Panther, T'Challa, is a trained scientist who also invented the Quinjet.  The same article says that he studied abroad.  He clearly has advanced engineering skills.

**Where did T'Challa go to school?**

Comment: You should have a look @ this page: http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/T%27Challa_(Earth-616)

Comment: He studied a broad?

Comment: @Valorum That was a hidden reference to a Howard Stark line in one of the movies. Glad someone noticed it.

Comment: @Valorum The one where Tony tells Howard he is studying abroad and Howard asks what her name is. I think MCU has a few "studying a broad" jokes in various movies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

T'Challa Black Panther went to graduate school at Oxford University in England and received a PhD in Physics. That's from this [Wikia article](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/T%27Challa_(Earth-616)), citing the [*Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A-Z* Vol 1:1](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Official_Handbook_of_the_Marvel_Universe_A-Z_Vol_1_1).

> He gained a Ph.D. in Physics from Oxford University.

The [official wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Black_Panther_(T'Challa)#axzz4n1N1Rvl5) lists "Ph.D in physics" under "Education," but does not name a location.

Comment: Technically as it was awarded by Oxford University it should be a DPhil in Physics.

Comment: Wouldn't the physics they teach at Oxford by rather primitive by Wakandan standards? I guess maybe he went for the culture or something.